# How can I get the text color of a system UITableVIewCell's detail label?

Tags: ios, system, rgb, textcolor

I really like that feeling.

and there are also some other systems color which I cannot find their API in UIColor document,

such as the default text color of the button in the nib file, etc.

so is there any way I can use them?

I mean, they are just colors, no risk ,right?

Or is there any the RGBA value that looks alike them? thanks a lot!

Comment: i think you ask about cell.detailTextLabel.textColor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] textColor]
```

textColor will just return the UIColor object of the cells detailTextLabel.

Comment: Printing this yields the equivalent of `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.22 green:0.33 blue:0.53 alpha:1]`, FYI.

Comment: as of iOS 9, the value returned is Color: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.556863 0.556863 0.576471 1, or in RGB values from 0-255, (142, 142, 147).

Answer (score 2):

By pulling a screenshot of the simulator into Photoshop, I get the following value:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.22 green:0.33 blue:0.55 alpha:1.0]
```

Looks pretty close to my eye on the device.  But muffe2k's answer will always work.

Answer (score 0):

I use `[UIColor grayColor]` for `UITableViewCell.detailsTextLabel.textColor`. At the first glance there is no diference betwen grayColor and original one.